# SQL Join Update table

Tags: sql, proc-sql

I have two tables, Table A has user Id and 5 different product columns(empty, to be filled by count ). Table B has timestamp user id and product id ( purchased at time t). This code id giving error

```
update table_A as table_A 
  set Count_Product_1 = (select count(product_ID)
                         from Table_B inner join Table_A 
                           on Table_A.User_ID=Table_B.User_ID 
                         where Product_ID = 'Unique_identifier_product_1');
```

> error: You cannot reopen Table_A for update access with member-level
>   control because Table_A is in use by you in resource environment SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing that you want a correlated subquery, not a general subquery.  Perhaps this does what you want:

```
update table_A as a 
    set Count_Product_1 = (select count(b.product_ID)
                           from Table_B b
                           where a.User_ID = b.User_ID and
                                 b.Product_ID = 'Unique_identifier_product_1'
                          );
```

This just seems like a more reasonable query.

Comment: thanks Its working , however my table has 400,000+ records so its taking time in (SAS Env) , results awaited.

Comment: An index on `table_B(user_id, product_id)` would help speed the query.